# Hölder continuity of gradient

Tags: regularity-theory-of-pdes, elliptic-operators

i would to like know what fact in the pde theory is used in the following article , pg 15

"Since $Dw$ is Hölder continuous, we can see this equation as a linear ellip-
tic equation with $C^{\alpha}$ coefficients. The standard Calderon-Zygmund theory
provides local $C^{2,\alpha}$ regularity on $w$ (bootstrapping the argument gives even
C∞ regularity on w)."

https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.06391

Thnaks

Answer (score 1):

The result the paper references is commonly referred to as [Schauder estimates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_estimates), which are a collection of results which (roughly) assert that if $u$ is a solution to a linear elliptic PDE of the form $Lu=f$ whose coefficients in $C^{\alpha},$ then $f \in C^{\alpha}$ implies that $u \in C^{2,\alpha}.$

You can find the details in most texts on elliptic PDE, such as Chapter 6 of Gilbarg and Trudinger.